# logarithmic calibration and geometric mean - citation search

Tags: standard-error, error, measurement-error, geometric-distribution

I have a logarithmic calibration line:

MachineSignal = -3.21 log(concentration) + 21.9

It seems obvious to me, that if I have a triplicate measurement of concentrations (measured indirectly through MachineSignal), they should be "averaged" by the geometric mean, not the arithmetic mean. (Arithmetic mean would be O.K. only for raw MachineSignal values.)

Can I have some authoritatively - looking citation for that ? I need it for the research paper I am writing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this obvious rule for averaging is not always the correct one. The answer depends on the nature of the measurement errors.  If on the machine scale they are homoscedastic then the arithmetic mean has a better justification than the geometric mean. A common example is a pH meter: the "machine signal" is the number on the meter; the dispersion of its measurement errors will be fairly consistent across its range of applicability. One puzzling aspect of your question is the reference to "raw MachineSignal values": how do these differ from the left side of the equation?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. However, the line is usually very nice in this measurement, R2 bigger than 0.9 . If you arithmetically average the machine signal for triplicates, the R2 gets even higher. Only, at the low concentrations near detection limit, the machine signal becomes highly scattered. The method in question is real-time PCR. Actually, it is habit to do arithmetic mean of concentrations, not geometric as I did :-(